# Function to pull email addresses in a specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

The data set looks like this:

```
V1023897@gmail.com
E3028753@gmail.com
```

The format is 1 character followed by 7 numerical values.

Little lost on what function to start off with. Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you!

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result, and show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're attempting to do is called "pattern matching", and in SQL Server it's carried out with the operator [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) inside the `WHERE` clause.

If you know in advance that your column contains emails, from which you want to take the ones having the format:

- one letter
- seven numbers
- @
- domain

you can use the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emails
WHERE email LIKE '[A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]@%'
```

**Pattern Explanation**:

- `[A-Za-z]`: a character in range A-Z or a-z
- `[0-9]`: a number in range 0-9
- ...
- `@`: @ character
- `%`: any other sequence of characters

**Output**:

| email |
| --- |
| V1023897@gmail.com |
| E3028753@gmail.com |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NVyrWlGz).